# Swift UI collection view layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to use a UIcollectionView in my SpriteKit game to display the level select scene. The collection view has 6 sections (start, world 1-5) with 8 cells in each (level 1-8). They are custom cells with a simple UILabel for now.
I can use the did select item for index path to load my levels, it's all good. However my problem is the following

The first section in the collection view is the start screen so I don't want the collection view to show the 8 cells in that section. That section is supposed o only showing a background image and a tap to start lable. So what I tried in cellForIndexPath is to

1) hide cells in that section but that causes text label issues with the cells in the other sections

2) hide the text labels and make the cells color transparent, same problem as 1

So basically what could I do to solve this issue?

I could put the start section into a different SKScene but I prefer if it's all in the collection view.
Another option I was thinking is to make each section have only 1 cell, the size of screen, and add 8 UIButtons to each section except the start section.
I also need some of those cells/buttons to be disabled until the previous level is unlocked. I am not sure what a better approach is, 8 cells as buttons or 8 UIButtons in 1 cell.

I am only looking for a UICollectionView solution, I already have an alternative, because it will make my life much easier when converting to tvOS and using the focus stuff and navigating through 6 sections with 30+ buttons

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register more that one kind of cell in UICollectionView:

- If you are using Interface builder add another Collection View Cell from Objects library and set it's reuse identifier
- Otherwise register nib or class in `viewDidLoad` method of your UICollectionViewController using `self.collectionView?.registerNib(forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` or `self.collectionView?.registerClass(forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`

Then when you dequeue cell use proper reuse identifier:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var reuseIdentifier = "identifier of cell with 8 button"
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        reuseIdentifier = "identifier of start cell as you set in IB of viewDidLoad"
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell depending on indexPath

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for. New to UiKit so this is all fairly new to me. I was actually trying this at one point but my problem was the let cell = ... line. I was writing it like this " let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell". The as! MyCustomCell caused me issues when trying to use 2 cells. Didnt realise you dont need that line. Thank you again

Comment: If I actually may ask you one more question. Using your way is working great. If I decide to switch back to using 8 cells instead of 1 with 8 buttons cell is there a similar trick of how to change the cell size in section 1 (0). I am using the flowLayout so I am defining the item size in the collection view and not in the custom cell.

Comment: `as! MyCustomCell` means that you want to *forcefully* cast cell to `MyCustomCell` class, when you have 2 different cells one (probably) is of another class so it will fail. you can specify class of your cell in Interface Builder

Comment: you should make custom UICollectionViewDelegate that implements UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, implement method `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` and return different size based on indexPath

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for 8 cells as buttons rather than using 1 cell with a series of UIButtons, that will keep things simple and allow you to use didSelectItemAtIndexPath.  Can't you just use numberOfItemsInSection to define only 1 cell in the first section?

My approach would probably be to use a custom flow layout and a supplementary view for your background image and tap to start button - a bit complex but very flexible.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help too. I will now most likely just use 8 cells in combination with what Piotrek suggested which is having 2 custom cells. I didnt full understand cell creation with 2 custom cell. Thanks again for your help